# Recording the time during serial port communication in matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, serial-port, fopen, fwrite

I am using Matlab commands `fopen`, `fwrite`and `fscanf` to open a line of serial port communication between two laptops using the following code:

**On laptop #1**:

```
   portID='/dev/tty.USA28Z145P2.2'
   s=serial(portID)
   fopen(s)
   fwrite(s,'67')
```

**On laptop #2**:

```
   s=serial('COM3')
   fopen(s)
   out=fscanf(s)
```

From the script I am running, sometimes the fwrite is 67 and sometimes 83. `Out` is able to record all of these.

I am trying to find a way to record the exact time at which each `fscanf` occurs, is this possible? I am collecting some other data and these commands run while the data acquisition is taking place and I need to find a way to record the time when each `fscanf` occurs so that I can sync it with my other data.

For e.g. if the COM3 port scans '67' I need to know at which time exactly this is because for my data collection '67' signifies the beginning of a 12 second period.

Does anybody know how to do this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Maheen

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not simply grab the current time when you call `fscanf` via `clock`, `now`, etc?

Comment: Also, are you expecting MATLAB to grab the data from multiple sources in real time or are different systems acquiring all of the different data?

Comment: @Suever matlab is acquiring data from a single source. Its a spectrometer which is connected via a serial port as well. I have tried using clock in my script but it gives me the date and time etc. but overwrites all the previous acquisitions. I use it like: `out=fscanf(s); c=clock' and then check what out and c are. out records all of the values from the beginning but clock does not

Comment: You would need to actually store the different time stamps in a cell array or numeric array of some sort, otherwise they *will* be overwritten every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never achieve a timing precision which I would call exact, because your software stack (MATLAB + operating System) has no real time capabilities.

If you are asking for a way to have a clock precision which is typically within a 0.1s error window, use the `BytesAvailableFcn` callback of the serial object.

The configuration would be

```
s=serial('COM3')
s.BytesAvailableFcn=@myCallback
s.BytesAvailableFcnCount=1
s.BytesAvailableFcnMode='byte'
fopen(s)
```

Where `myCallback` is a function you have to implement which is always called whenever bytes are available.

```
function myCallback(obj,event)
    disp(event.Data.Time); %print time data is received
    %obj is your serial object, use existing code to read.
end
```

[Further details in the documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/events-and-callbacks.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to understand how I would use this function in my script. To put it simply, I want to record the time at which each "67" or "83" is scanned because it signifies the beginning of a time period.

Comment: Thanks for this, thats very useful as is the documentation! I will give it a go once I have everything set up again tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for this!! I created a callback function and it works perfectly.